# exit(1) in file results in script status code 0

Tags: php

On Ubuntu machine:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.10-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2014 18:55:59) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with uopz v2.0.4, Copyright (c) 2014, by Joe Watkins <krakjoe@php.net>
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

My test.php file is simple:

```
<?php 
exit(1);
```

I would expect this command `php test.php || echo "error"` to show "error" but it exits with status code 0.

```
$ php test.php
$ echo $?
0
```

But on the same machine the same code, but not in file works as expected:

```
$ php -r "exit(1);" || echo "error"
error
```

or

```
$ php -r "exit(1);"
$ echo $?
1
```

On different machine (archlinux) with php:

```
PHP 5.5.13 (cli) (built: May 29 2014 05:46:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

All cases work as expected, even when the code is run from file the status code is 1.

This is a true problem because git hooks depends on this status codes and Jenkins and I couldn't google it out.

Could it be somehow config-related? I checked cli php.ini and couldn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: The first time you start `php` and the other times you start `php5`. Maybe there's a difference in that?

Comment: That's weird. It works here: http://codepad.org/04NRRPxe.

Comment: Works as expected on my machine: https://pastee.org/9fk8k

Comment: @GolezTrol the same situation is on php and php5 (actually the same executable). Sorry for confusing example (fixed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `uopz` extension is the problem. It "corrupts" the exit code. There was a [bug](https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz/issues/2) opened about this issue.

You can try to set the configuration `uopz.overloads=0` as it was recommended in the bug comments. That, unfortunately didn't work for me. Only disabling the extension fixed the issue.